Assist me in determining whether the analysis process using the limma package has been executed correctly
I utilized the R package GEOquery to download data from the GEO database, followed by DFG analysis using the limma package. However, I am uncertain whether this process is accurate. The DFG output indicates that each P-value is significant, but each adjusted P-value tends towards 1. I attempted this process with several datasets using the limma R package and encountered the same outcome consistently. Thus, I suspect an error in my analysis code. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my analysis code and its corresponding output:
options(stringsAsFactors = F) 
suppressMessages(library(GEOquery))
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(limma)

gset <- getGEO('GSE98421', destdir=".", AnnotGPL = F, getGPL = F)
gse <- gset[[1]]
exp <- exprs(gse)
# Clinic data ("NL woman","PCOS woman")
meta.data <- pData(gse) 
group_list <- sapply(meta.data$description, function(x) 
    unlist(strsplit(x," "))[1])
group_list <- factor(group_list,levels = c("NL","PCOS"))
table(group_list)
# Change ID names
gpl <- getGEO('GPL570', destdir=".")
probe.gene <- Table(gpl)[,c("ID","Gene Symbol")]
colnames(probe.gene) <- c("ID","Symbol")
probe.gene <- subset(probe.gene, Symbol != '')
ids <- probe.gene
ids$Symbol <- data.frame(sapply(ids$Symbol, function(x) 
    unlist(strsplit(x,"///"))[1]), stringsAsFactors = F)[,1]
head(ids)

library(tidyverse)
exp <- as.data.frame(exp) 
exp <- exp %>% 
  mutate(ID = rownames(exp)) %>% 
  inner_join(ids, by = "ID") %>%
  select(ID, Symbol, everything())

table(duplicated(exp$Symbol))
exp.unique <- avereps(exp[, -c(1,2)], ID = exp$Symbol)

# DFG analysis
design <- model.matrix(~0+factor(group_list))
colnames(design) <- levels(factor(group_list))
rownames(design) <- colnames(exp.unique)

fit <- lmFit(exp.unique,design)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(paste0(c("NL","PCOS"),collapse = "-"),levels = design)
fit2 <- contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix) 
fit2 <- eBayes(fit2) 
DiffEG <- topTable(fit2, coef=1, n=Inf) %>% na.omit()
head(DiffEG)


enter image description here
Can I use alternative methods for DFG analysis to identify significantly differentially expressed genes (DFGs)?
